# Trouble Understanding %>%

Tags: r, magrittr

I am having a huge amount of trouble understanding %>%

I need an example to understand this. Here is my simple example:

```
v <- c("the cat the cat ran up the tree tree", "the dog ran up the up the tree", 
         "the squirrel squirrel ran up the tree")
```

The desired output is:

```
"the cat ran up the tree"
"the dog ran up the tree"
"the squirrel ran up the tree"
```

I wish to take:

```
v <- gsub('kat', 'cat', v) 
v <- gsub('dogg', 'dog', v) 
v <- gsub('squirrel', 'squirrrel', v)
```

And use:

```
gsub('kat', 'cat', v) %>%
gsub('dogg', 'dog', v) %>%
gsub('squirrel', 'squirrrel', v)
```

Can someone correct this for me?

I get the error:

```
Warning message:
In gsub(., "dogg", "dog", v) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pipe` will by default place values into the first parameter of the next function. if you need to place the value in a different parameter position, you need to use the special `.` variable to indicate where you want it to go. For example

```
v %>% 
  gsub('kat', 'cat', .) %>%
  gsub('dogg', 'dog', .) %>%
  gsub('squirrel', 'squirrrel', .)
```